# Microservices - How to model a register flow with Authorization Server and Resource Server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, architecture, microservices

I'm using Java and Spring Boot to implement a Microservice ecosystem.

I have 3 logical boundaries:

- Medicines (Resource Server)
- Appointments (Resource Server)
- Identity Federation (Authorization Server)

User's login information (username, password, roles, etc..) goes into the `Identity Federation` Microservice.
User's personal information (first name, last name, address, contact mediums, gender, etc..) goes into the `Appointments` Microservice.

Now, imagine a situation where at my `Appointments Resource Server` I have the following resource exposed:

- `GET /doctors/{id}` - returns the personal information about the Doctor with the passed id

And at my `Identity Federation Authorization Server` I have the following:

- `POST /oauth/token` - a resource that returns a token.

Now, imagine that I `POST` to `/oauth/token` at my Authorization Server and I got authenticated and receive a token.

Ok, now, I can use this token to do transactions with the Resource Servers.

If I send a `GET` to `/doctor/1`, my token gets parsed and I can read all of its claims. Roles, User Id, Username, etc..

The Doctor with id = 1 should not be able to see the personal information of other Doctor (eg.: Doctor with id = 4).

So, when the request arrives at `/doctors/1`, I need to check if the id on the token is the same that is being requested.

In Spring, would be something like this:

```
@GetMapping("/doctors/{id}")
@PreAuthorize("#id == authentication.doctorId")
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleGetDoctorsInformations(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    // logic and return
}
```

But to be able to do that, I need to synchronize the ids on both Microservices (Appointments Resource Server and Identity Federation Authorization Server).

I can't use a Natural Key because I have three types of users (Doctor is just one of them) that can log-in, and the Natural Keys are different for both.

So, the id needs to be generated in somewhere.
I'm not sure which is the best way to it.

What our team have discussed:

[image: flow]

Basically:

1. The front-end `POST` to Authorization Server with a whole Doctor JSON payload (with personal information AND login information).
2. The Authorization Server creates an account generating its unique id.
3. The Authorization Server increment the JSON payload with the generated id and then publishes the JSON to the Queue.
4. The Resource Server listens to the Queue, get the JSON and create the Doctor at his side, storing the Doctor personal Information.

**Is this a bad way to do it?**

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, you don't need to implement a queue with additional complexity just to verify special permission (here, read other doctors data) of a particular doctor. Instead, you can generate JWT token and embed specific privilege like 'READ_DOCTORS_INFO' on the payload of toke. Then your resource server which manages doctors information can verify provided token and allow specific user depending on the permissions embedded on JWT token.